What is the difference between (## and pts) the last sentence of these two pieces of code? What is the reason?
Clear["`*"]
pts = Table[{Cos[2  Pi  i/8], Sin[2  Pi  i/8]}, {i, 8}]
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #1, {2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #2, {-2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #3, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[D, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #4, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[E, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #5, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[F, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #6, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[G, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #7, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[H, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #8, {2, -1}]} &;
Graphics[{Line /@ Tuples[pts, 2], labels[##]}] & @@ pts

The above code can run correctly to obtain the desired result

But if we replace the original pts with # # on the last sentence of code with the following form, how can we not get the correct result?
Graphics[{Line /@ Tuples[##, 2], labels[##]}] & @@ pts

Clear["`*"]
pts = Table[{Cos[2  Pi  i/8], Sin[2  Pi  i/8]}, {i, 8}]
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #1, {2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #2, {-2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #3, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[D, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #4, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[E, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #5, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[F, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #6, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[G, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #7, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[H, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #8, {2, -1}]} &;
Graphics[{Line /@ Tuples[##, 2], labels[##]}] & @@ pts

get


Note there's Apply (@@) instead of @.

"##" returns a Sequence. Therefore "Tuples[##, 2]" is evaluated to "Tuples[p1,p2,..,2]", where pi are the point coordinates. You need to put a list around "##"

You're not learning, you're just guessing blindly, I don't see your effort.  (-1)


"##" returns a Sequence. Therefore "Tuples[##, 2]" is evaluated to "Tuples[p1,p2,..,2]", where pi are the point coordinates. You need to put a list around "##" –
Daniel Huber

According to Daniel Huber's prompt, the following code can solve the problem
Clear["`*"]
pts = Table[{Cos[2  Pi  i/8], Sin[2  Pi  i/8]}, {i, 8}]
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #1, {2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #2, {-2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #3, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[D, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #4, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[E, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #5, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[F, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #6, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[G, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #7, {2, -1}], 
    Text[Style[H, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #8, {2, -1}]} &;
Graphics[{Line /@ Tuples[{##}, 2], labels[##]}] & @@ pts


